# How to eliminate the looping from below code

Tags: list, linq, loops

I would like to eliminate the loops for better coding and improved performance. So, in below code I need to eliminate loop for test1, test 2, test3.

```
var test1 = _testP.cdata1(id, sdate)
                .Where(t => t.In != null).ToList();

var test2 = _testP.cdata2(id, sdate)
            .groupBy(p => p.In.id)
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.ToDictionary(q => q.Date, q => q));

var test3 = test1.Select(t =>
{
    Dictionary<Date, ClassB> cds = null;
    ClassB cd = null;

    if (test2.TryGetValue(t.In.Id, out cds)
        && cds.TryGetValue(t.date, out cd))
    {
        return new Tuple<ClassB, ClassA>(cd, t);
    }
    return null;
}).Where(p => p != null).ToList();


public IEnumerable<ClassA> cdata1(id, sdate)
{
    // do some operations
    return listA //(listA is the list of all the elements of ClassA object)
}

public IEnumerable<ClassB> cdata2(id, sdate)
{
    // do some operations
    return listA //(listA is the list of all the elements of ClassB object)            
}

public ClassA
{
    public testp in { get; }
    public Date date { get; }
    // other variables
}

public ClassB
{
    public testp in { get; }
    public Date date { get; }
    // other variables
}
```

Help me out on writing better code for the above snippet.

Comment: You should go to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Vote to move this into [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Code Review.

Comment: You do not have Id in ClassB. How can you use it in grouping? .groupBy(p => p.id)

Comment: @ManishM Updated the question. Please update me on the rewrite code.